# Time dependent Schrödinger equation queer solution

Tags: fortran, physics, gfortran

I am solving the evolution of time dependent schrodinger equation under a harmonic potential and an initial gaussian wavefunction . Treating `hcut=1` and `2m=1`, and seperating the wavefunction in real and imaginary parts, two coupled equations are obtained in terms of the real and imaginary part, termed as `yr` and `yc` respectively.

`xrange` is `[xi,xf]`
`trange` is `[0,tf]`

method I used is :

first seperating the wavefunction in real and imaginary part, namely yr(x,t) and yc(x,t) .
then treating hcut=2m=1, and writing the wavefunction as `yr[x,t]+i*yc[x,t]`,we get two coupled equations from the TDSE .

```
1.D[yr[x,t],t]=-D[yc[x,t],x,x]+V[x]*yc[x,t]
2.D[yc[x,t],t]=D[yc[x,t],x,x]-V[x]*yc[x,t]
```

Then I specified the inital wavefunction as

```
yr[x,0]=exp[-x^2]
yc[x,0]=0
```

After that, using finite difference scheme, I tried to find y[x,t] from y[x,0]
i.e,

```
yr[x,t+d]=yr[x,t]+d*D[yr[x,t],t]
        =yr[x,t]+d*(D[yc[x,t],x,x]+V[x]*yc[x,t])
```

indexed as "a" in code and "b" for the complex part .

The values of `y[x[i],t[j]]` are stored as `y[i,j]` as array cannot have real index .

The code I used is given below:

```
    function v(x) result(s)
    real::s,x
    s=x**2
    end function v

    real::t(10000),x(10000),yc(10000,10000),yr(10000,10000),tf,xi,xf,d
    integer::i,j,k,l,m,n,time
    write(*,*) "time of plot divided by step size"
    read(*,*) time

    tf=50
    xi=-10
    xf=10
    d=0.01
    x(1)=xi
    t(1)=0

    i=1
    do while(x(i).lt.xf)        !input all values of x in x(i) array
    x(i+1)=x(i)+d
    i=i+1
    end do

    n=1
    do while(t(n).lt.tf)        !input all values of t in t(i) array
    t(n+1)=t(n)+d
    n=n+1
    end do




    do j=1,i
    yr(j,1)=exp(-(x(j)-5)**2)       !input of initial wavefunction    
    yc(j,1)=0
    end do

    !calculation of wavefunction at higher time using finite element technique[y[x,t+d]=y[x]+d*D[y[x,t],t] and then replacing the partial derivative with time 
    !using equation 1 and 2 .

    l=1
    do while(l.le.i-2)
    k=1
         do while(t(k).lt.tf)
            yr(l,k+1)=yr(l,k)-(yc(l+2,k)-2*yc(l+1,k)+yc(l,k))/d&    
            +v(x(l))*yc(l,k)*d                                                                             

            yc(l,k+1)=yc(l,k)+(yr(l+2,k)-2*yr(l+1,k)+yr(l,k))/d&   
            -v(x(l))*yr(l,k)*d

            k=k+1

         end do
    l=l+1
    end do




    open(1,file="q.dat")
    do m=1,i-2
    write(1,*) x(m),(yr(m,time))**2+(yc(m,time))**2
    end do
    close(1)

    end
```

Expected result: y(x,t)^2=yr(x,t)^2+yc(x,t)^2

Error: The wavefunction is not staying regular, after only `t=0.05` or `0.06`, the wavefunction is turning huge and the maxima is becoming of the order of `e30`, in spite of that the gaussian shape is remaining almost unchanged, as expected, as only `0.05` seconds has passsed.

Comment: Please describe which mathematical method you are using and try to make your code more readable by using proper indentation. The structure should be apparent when looking at your code, but your code is rather a mess in this regard. Increase the indentation level in every do loop, if conditional and similar structure.

Comment: Especially describe which criterion do you use to choose the timestep.

Comment: excuse me, in our course we often use gotos and dont have idea why goto statement is being unwelcome .

Comment: @user157588 Since 1968 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful https://doi.org/10.1145%2F362929.362947

Comment: *"using finite difference scheme"* Which FD scheme in particular? Is the time stepping explicit? How did you choose the timestep? How do you assure stability?

Comment: Actually I am new in doing this kind of numerical problems . I chose the timestep as 0.01, arbitrarily . As there is no term such as 1/x or 1/x^2, choosing 0.01 should not cause large error, I think .

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a coding problem but a numerical mathematical one and I suggest you to first study some tutorials about numerical methods for the Schrödinger equation and similar PDEs and then ask for more at sites that are devoted to [scientific computation](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

First, the method you chose does not conserve the norm of the solution. That can be saved by normalizing by each time step, but it is quite ugly.

Second, the method you chose is explicit (actually, it is probably the forward Euler method that is unconditionally unstable). That means the allovable time step is going to be severly limited by diffusive-like term (even though it is complex here). A simple implicit method that also conserves the norm quite well is the [Crank-Nicolson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method). It is an implicit method and you will have to solve a system of linear equations at each timestep. It is quite simple in 1D as the system is tridiagonal. There are also some [explicit schemes that may work](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2157467?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), but they are more involved, not the naive scheme you tried.

Third, you do not have to split the system into the real part and the imaginary part, it can be done using complex numbers.

Fourth, you shoould keep your spatial grid step dx and time-step dt as separate variables with known values. You can compute the final coefficient `d` as their ratio, but you should at least know your values od dx and dt.

Fifth, you do not have to store all values of the solution in all time-steps. That will quickly become prohibitevely expenses in times of memory required for larger problems. It is enough to store the last time-step and the current time-step. More for multistep methods and some auxiliary steps for Runge-Kutta methods.

Comment: Could you please recommend a good resource for learning the computational methods as you stated in the answer ?

Comment: @user157588 I am not a specialist in this are, but googling for numerical Schrodinger equation shows many university courses and tutorials. Some general introduction into finite difference methods will help too.